# A problem about probability and unit square

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

How can I solve this problem?

> A point $P = (X, Y)$ of the unit square $(0,1) \times  (0,1)$ is chosen at random. Let $\theta$ be the angle formed between the $x-$axis and the segment joining the origin and $P$. Find the density of $\theta$.

---

I know for example that $\theta=\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{Y}{X}\right)$ and since that $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ so $X\sim \textbf{U}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim \textbf{U}(0,1)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.
But, I don't know how can I continue. In fact I don't quite understand the problem.

In my attempt, I think I could use the Jacobian transformation theorem, but I don't know how to approach the problem that way.

Comment: I think you could start by figuring out the CDF first. Consider some angle $\Theta$. What is the probability that the angle $\theta$ is smaller than $\Theta$ ? A graphical solution is easy ...

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. Do you say try to find first $\mathbb{P}(\Theta\leq \theta)$?

Comment: For example, I know that $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ so $0<\frac{y}{x}<1$.Then, since $\theta=\tan(y/x)$, we have $0<\theta<\pi/4$.

Comment: It doesn't follow that $\frac yx<1$ (the point $(0.1,0.9)$ is in the unit square). Careful with our algebraic steps with inequalities!

Comment: You're right. I was careless for a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can calculate the distribution of $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$

Without integrals, but only with a simple drawing you get

$$ F_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $z<0$ } \\
\frac{z}{2},  & \text{if $0\leq z<1$ } \\
1-\frac{1}{2z}, & \text{if $z\geq 1$}
\end{cases}$$

Then easy find the distribution of $\theta=arctan(Z)$ with the fundamental transformation theorem

$$ f_\Theta(\theta) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{tan^2\theta}{2},  & \text{if $0\leq \theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$ } \\
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 tan^2\theta}, & \text{if $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

---

**Solution details & explanation**

How to derivate $F_Z(z)$?

Frist of all observe that $Z \in [0;\infty)$.

Using the definition we have

$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}[Z\leq z]=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq zX]$$

Let's do a drawing:

[image]
Z-CDF is the purple area...

Immeditately find $f_Z(z)$ derivating F

and also easy find the density of $\Theta=tan^{-1}(Z)$ simply applying the known formula

$$f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\Bigg|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\Bigg|$$

Comment: I'm sorry. but I don't see how $ F_ {Z} (z) $ is found. Although you mention that it is simple, I do not see the direct relationship. Could you write the steps of the solution? I would sincerely like to learn from the solution.

Comment: I'm just starting to train probability theory and I'm still very slow with problem solving.

Comment: @Ramanujan : added some details for the solution. I hope this helps

Comment: Ok, Now I understand the problem and a little the solution. Can a explain me, why if $0\leq z<1$ so $F_{Z}(z)=\frac{z}{2}$? Honestly, that construction of $F_{Z}(z)$ is the one that I'm not seeing clearly.

Comment: @Ramanujan : $F_Z=P(Z<z)$, It is the integral of $f(x,y)=1$ over the interested support. As per the fact that the integrand is 1, we have that $F_Z$ is the integration area. When $z<1$ the area is a triangle with base 1 and height z. Thus $F=\frac{z}{2}$. When $Z>1$ the purple area is calculated as $1$ minus the area of the little white triangle with base $\frac{1}{z}$ and height 1, Thus $F_Z=1-\frac{1}{2z}$

Comment: You're right! Now I saw the solution clearly! Many thanks for your explication @tommik.

Comment: +1 upvote. Excellent explication.